# Reverse Linked List in C++ Using Only Node Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes

My teacher left this task:

> Reverse the order of the elements of a linked list, only by manipulating pointers in each node. It is not allowed to move the item as such, nor is to create a new node for this operation.

I've tried to think in a solution for this but everytime I end up needing to create a new node pointer or calling another method that returns a created one.

Here's some code, the list is singly linked, "first" is the head of the list and "last" is the last pointer of the list.

My method for getting a node pointer:

```
template <class T>
Node<T>* LinkedList<T>::getNode(unsigned int i)
{
    int index = 0;
    if (i == 0)
        return first;
    Node<T>* cursor = first;
    while (index != i && cursor)
    {
        cursor = cursor->getNext();
        ++index;
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

And, here's my method for reverse the list:

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::reverse()
{
    int i = 1, j = 2;
    while(j <= size)
    {
        getNode(size - 1)->setNext(getNode(size - j++));
        if (j == size + 1)
            first = getNode(size - (j - 2));
        else
            getNode(size - j)->setNext(getNode(size - i++));
        getNode(size - 1)->setNext(nullptr);
    }
    last = getNode(size - 1);
}
```

As I said before, I needed to know if there's a way for me to do the same without using that get method (which creates a node pointer). I think that when he refers to create a new node he's talking about a node pointer because you can't create a node (an object not a pointer) and assign to it a pointer of the list.

IF there's a way I'd be really gratefull if someone shares it, and if there's no way then I'll do it the normal way. Thanks to the people who has answered.

Comment: This isn't a homework dumping site, please post your effort and present a specific problem and we'll be glad to assist you

Comment: This may sound trite, but it isn't meant to be so: Get a piece of paper and a pencil, start drawing boxes with arrows. There is no better visually expressive way of formulating a linked list algorithm. When that fails (whether or not that failure is because you didn't bother trying), there are conservatively a *thousand* examples throughout the web of reversing the pointers in a linked list, likely at least a half-dozen on this site alone. Google-fu it. Until you've *tried*, and bring us your attempt with specific questions, not much we can do.

Comment: Post whatever you have tried.

Comment: Is it a singly linked list or a doubly linked list?

Comment: You're allowed to create a pointer to a node that already exists, just not to a new node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Singly Linked List

IMO, the easiest method is to create a new head pointer, then take the elements of the existing list and *push* them to the top of the new list.

```
         +---+     +---+     +---+  
Head --> | A | --> | B | --> | C |  
         +---+     +---+     +---+
```

**Move First Node to new List:**

```
             +---+    
New List --> | A |    
             +---+   

         +---+     +---+  
Head --> | B | --> | C |  
         +---+     +---+
```

**Push the next node onto the new list.**

```
             +---+     +---+    
New List --> | B | --> | A |    
             +---+     +---+     

         +---+  
Head --> | C |  
         +---+
```

**Repeat until all nodes from original list are pushed to the new list:**

```
             +---+     +---+     +---+    
New List --> | C | --> | B | --> | A |    
             +---+     +---+     +---+
```

*The actual coding is left as an exercise for the OP.*
*Note:  Only pointers in the node have changed.  Actual node data has not been altered, or moved.*

### Doubly Linked List

With a doubly linked list, you need to swap the *next* pointer with the "previous" pointer.

```
           +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  
Head   --> |  A  |  |  B  |  |  C  |  
           +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  
(Previous) |  /  |  | <-- |  + <-- |  
           +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  
(Next)     | --> |  | --> |  |  /  |  
           +-----+  +-----+  +-----+
```

After swapping:

```
           +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  
           |  A  |  |  B  |  |  C  |  <-- Head  
           +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  
(Previous) | --> |  | --> |  |  /  |  
           +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  
(Next)     |  /  |  | <-- |  + <-- |  
           +-----+  +-----+  +-----+
```

### Example Code for Single Linked List

```
struct Node
{
  int data;
  Node * p_next;
};

void Reverse_List(Node * & p_list)
{
  Node * p_new_list = NULL;
  while (p_list != NULL)
  {
    // Disconnect node from original list.
    Node * p_node = p_list;
    p_list = p_node->p_next;
    p_node->p_next = NULL;

    // Push node to new list
    p_node->p_next = p_new_list;
    p_new_list = p_node;
  }

  //  Set passed pointer to new list
  p_list = p_new_list;
}
```

Making the code generic is left as an exercise to for the OP.

Comment: Thank you, I used a modified version of your method since apparently there's no way to manipulate the pointers without creating at least a temp pointer for it.